# Not available for deploy for this API version

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm not able to deploy Lightning Message Channel.

**Error: Not available for deploy for this API version**

## Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <masterLabel>Record</masterLabel>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <description>This Lightning Message Channel sends information from VF to LWC</description>

   <lightningMessageFields>
       <fieldName>messageToSend</fieldName>
       <description>message To Send</description>
   </lightningMessageFields>

   <lightningMessageFields>
       <fieldName>sourceSystem</fieldName>
       <description>My source?</description>
   </lightningMessageFields>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LightningMessageChannel`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_lightningmessagechannel.htm) was introduced in API version 47.0. If you are deploying your source using an earlier API version, you must upgrade in order to deploy this component.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed